# Typescript referencing a module from internet and in local tests

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, bundle, browserify

I'm trying to not bundle everything with the typescript game that I'm developing. I've had success with de-bundling the 2D game-engine `pixi.js` by doing these:

in .html:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/5.3.3/pixi.min.js"></script>
```

in compilation root (`main.ts`)

```
/// <reference types="pixi.js" />
```

As a result I have been able to remove all of the

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'
```

statements from the individual files and is able to shave about 50% from the bundled script (created by browserify and minify).

---

However, when I need a module with default exports which are also reflected in local testing (using `chai`), there's a problem, e.g.:

```
import SimplexNoise from 'simplex-noise'
```

I have verified that the game can still run by putting

```
<script type="module" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simplex-noise/2.4.0/simplex-noise.js"></script>
```

in the html file and replace the aforementioned `import` statement with

```
// @ts-nocheck
```

However, local testing suite depend on the local import statement being there.

Is there a way to satisfy both local testing requirements and remove the package from bundle? I know I can manually remove the package from browserify using `browserify -i simplex-noise ..` but when I tried this the game stop running because it tries to `require('simplex-noise')` but the script tag creates the namespace `SimplexNoise` automatically.

AFAIK, unlike python, you can't do below in javascript.

```
if (local) {
    import ...
}
```

Comment: May be you can add it as a dev only dependency and use it. While testing, bundle size should not matter. So you may have proper packages during it. Also having npm dependency may help you in having better typing if they have `index.d.ts` file

Comment: @Rajesh I use typescript native tests with `ts-node` so bundling was not involved. I only wanted the package removed from the final bundling product. The problem is not with excluding the package, but recognizing it when using `<script>` in html without doing too much manual voodoo. Also, all of them are devDependencies in `package.json`